# Servicio C# de Windows-SDK Hikvision muestra mensaje "el servicio se inicio correctamente" Pero no realiza el proceso

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, servicio

Realice un servicio de Windows con un intervalo de 60000 milisegundos(1 minuto) para el tema de la replicacion de imagenes en cada uno de los relojes que tengo disponibles; con el SDK de hikvision. He realizado pruebas del servicio en modo Debug, de esta manera valido que si replica las imágenes en cada uno de los relojes y al mismo tiempo me registra en mi base de datos en que relojes ya se realizo la actualización.

Al instalar mi servicio en mi maquina local, inicio el servicio y en el visor de eventos únicamente muestra el mensaje que el servicio se inicio correctamente.

Las imagenes las tengo en una carpte local en mi ordenador
Tengo mi connectionString para el tema de insercion de data en la DB

No se si esto infiera en algo

Ruta de mi carpeta en el AppConfig, ahi tambien tengo los demas valore para la conexion, etc.

```
<add key="DirectorioPicture" value="C:\Users\dsolares\Documents\Pruebas desarrollo\Evento Foto" />



 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
 {
     timer1.Start();
     EventLog.WriteEntry("Inicio de proceso de Actualizacion de Biometros", EventLogEntryType.Information);

 }

 protected override void OnStop()
 {
     timer1.Stop();
     EventLog.WriteEntry("Se detuvo el proceso de Actualizacion de Biometros", EventLogEntryType.Information);
 }

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     timer1.Stop();

     try
     {
         EventLog.WriteEntry("Inicio de proceso de Actualizacion de Biometros", EventLogEntryType.Information);

         //Obtener el listado de los dispositivos desde la DB
         var ListaDispositivos = GetDeviceList();


         //Iteramos sobre cada uno de los relojes disponibles
         for (int dispositivoBiometrico = 0; dispositivoBiometrico < ListaDispositivos.Count; dispositivoBiometrico++)
         {
             //Actualizar la imagen de cada uno de los empleados a cada dispositivo 
             List<string> file_list = new List<string>();
             //hacemos uso de la funcion "searchDirectory, para hacer referencia la ruta completa
             SearchDirectory(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirectorioPicture"].ToString(), file_list);

             //iteramos sobre la lista de dispositivos pasandole cada una de las imagenes disponibles
             for (int imagenLocal = 0; imagenLocal < file_list.Count; imagenLocal++)
             {
                 FileInfo file = new FileInfo(file_list[imagenLocal]);
                 Actualizar_ImagenesDispositivos(ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].DireccionIP, ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].Puerto.ToString(),
                     ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].Usuario, ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].Clave, file.Name.Replace(".jpg", ""), file_list[imagenLocal]);
             }
         }
         EventLog.WriteEntry("Fin de proceso de Actualizacion de Biometros", EventLogEntryType.Information);

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Information);
     }
     timer1.Start();
     EventLog.WriteEntry("Se actulizo correctamente la replicacion de imagenes", EventLogEntryType.Information);

 }
```

Comment: En "Services" has visto si se detiene o no se detiene pero no llama al método que realiza el proceso?

Comment: @Jorgesys el servicio no se detiene, una vez lo inicio y se queda ejecutando, pero no realiza el proceso

Comment: Cuál es el método que realiza el "proceso"? @dsr

Comment: @Jorgesys la funcion  private void timer1_Tick

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no estás llamando ningún proceso, en tu método `OnStart()`, deberías definir el `timer` y mediante un `ElapseEventHandler` definir el método que realizaría el "proceso".

Revisa este ejemplo, en este caso es `timer1_Tick` el método que realiza el proceso :

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            // Update the service state to Start Pending.
            ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
            serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING;
            serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 100000;
            SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
            EventLog.WriteEntry("OnStart() Inicio de proceso de Actualizacion de Biometros", EventLogEntryType.Information);
            // Set up a timer that triggers every minute.
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 60000; // 60 seconds
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
            timer.Start();   
     }
```

En este método ya no es necesario definir un "Timer", ya que este y su intervalo de ejecución se definió en `OnStart()`:

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //timer1.Stop();

     try
     {
         EventLog.WriteEntry("Inicio de proceso de Actualizacion de Biometros", EventLogEntryType.Information);

         //Obtener el listado de los dispositivos desde la DB
         var ListaDispositivos = GetDeviceList();


         //Iteramos sobre cada uno de los relojes disponibles
         for (int dispositivoBiometrico = 0; dispositivoBiometrico < ListaDispositivos.Count; dispositivoBiometrico++)
         {
             //Actualizar la imagen de cada uno de los empleados a cada dispositivo 
             List<string> file_list = new List<string>();
             //hacemos uso de la funcion "searchDirectory, para hacer referencia la ruta completa
             SearchDirectory(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirectorioPicture"].ToString(), file_list);

             //iteramos sobre la lista de dispositivos pasandole cada una de las imagenes disponibles
             for (int imagenLocal = 0; imagenLocal < file_list.Count; imagenLocal++)
             {
                 FileInfo file = new FileInfo(file_list[imagenLocal]);
                 Actualizar_ImagenesDispositivos(ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].DireccionIP, ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].Puerto.ToString(),
                     ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].Usuario, ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].Clave, file.Name.Replace(".jpg", ""), file_list[imagenLocal]);
             }
         }
         EventLog.WriteEntry("Fin de proceso de Actualizacion de Biometros", EventLogEntryType.Information);

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Information);
     }
     //timer1.Start();
     EventLog.WriteEntry("Se actulizo correctamente la replicacion de imagenes", EventLogEntryType.Information);

 }
```

Revisa la documentación:

[**Define que ocurre cuando el servicio inicia**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer#define-what-occurs-when-the-service-starts)